# Action hook for editing post

Tags: actions

I'm looking for the add_action() hook for when a current post is edited and saved. I know there's `edit_post` and `save_post`, but I'm looking for something that ONLY fires when a current post is edited, not created or altered in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer.

Take a look the files that use [save_post](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/save_post?version=3.4&file=wp-includes/post.php) and [edit_post](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_post?version=3.4&file=wp-includes/post.php)
It will lead you to the hook [post_updated](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/post_updated)

Take a look and see if you can find a hook you need. Keep in mind that you might need to do some checks in the hook.
You'll figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, I have an idea of how I could do it. Thanks, I'll just except this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The codex doesn't really give much information but it does look like `edit_post` is the hook to use.

> edit_post 
>   Runs when a post or page is updated/edited, including when a comment is added or updated (which causes the comment count for the post to update). Action function arguments: post or page ID.